# Is there an easy way to write a basic dependency manager in JS like RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, callback, dependencies, requirejs, dependency-management

I want to write a basic script that can function as a dependency manager like RequireJS (but not as complex).

Ideally, like RequireJS, I'd like to be able to call a function, and give the function an array of scripts to load and a callback to call when the scripts are finished loading. I'm thinking of something like the following:

```
myRequireFunc(['scriptA', 'scriptB', 'scriptC'], function () {
  // Callback code here
});
```

Following the following SO thread, I was able to make some progress with dynamically loading scripts and then calling a callback when they're all loaded, but the issue I'm having now is what to do when scriptA, scriptB or scriptC has a dependency of its own:
[Dynamically load external javascript file, and wait for it to load - without using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586446/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-and-wait-for-it-to-load-without-usi)

Can anyone please offer some advice/direction on how to handle dependencies so that a call to `myRequireFunc` will not call the callback until all scripts ***and all dependencies of those scripts*** have loaded?

Comment: What's wrong with requirejs itself?

Comment: You need to build a transitive dependency graph, collapse it, and build the complete list.

Comment: Pointy, there's nothing wrong with RequireJS. It's great, actually. More than anything, I was just trying to walk myself through the process to learn. Also, Dave Newton, I apologize, but I cannot understand your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: did you check yepnopejs for solution?