# Load javascript after 2 clicks on website

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that I want to load when the user has clicked two times on my website. I have no clue how to this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: more description pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  var count = 1
  $(document).click(function(){
    if(count<=2){
      count+=1;
    }
    else{
      alert("already clicked two times");
    }   
  });
})
```

this will start showing the alert after the 2nd click. You can write the code to load the javascript instead of this alert.

Comment: Thanks man!! How would you put this within the <head> section?

Comment: @user3637351 Sorry sir I dont understand your question, Do you mean how will we paste it inside script tags within head?

Comment: I want to load a script that I have external after the else statement and I want to put this in my <head> tag

Comment: @user3637351 I think this can be useful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586446/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-and-wait-for-it-to-load-without-usi