# From js to script

Tags: javascript

in a recent post   [Load javascript after 2 clicks on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228568/load-javascript-after-2-clicks-on-website/26228630#26228630) I asked about a javascript issue.

```
  $(function(){
          var count = 1
          $(document).click(function(){
            if(count<=2){
              count+=1;
           }
           else{
              alert("already clicked two times");
           }   
        });
     })
```

Problem is now that I want to have this javascript it inside script tags in my `<head>` but then this script wont work, can someone help me through how they would write their script? Thanks!!

Update:

```
  <head>
    <script>
  $(function(){
          var count = 1
          $(document).click(function(){
            if(count<=2){
              count+=1;
           }
           else{
              alert("already clicked two times");
           }
        });
     })
     </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Telling us it "won't work" isn't very helpful. Show us your attempt to use `<script>` tags. It should be as simple as using `<script>` before your code and `</script>` after.

Comment: It's in a ready event handler, so there's no obvious reason why putting it in the `<head>` would break things.

Comment: Well, it's not working. if I put this within a script tag and a <head>

Comment: You should include jQuery library first.

Comment: check: 1. included jquery library? 2. <script> tag must be after include lib tag

Comment: and tell us your code position in the HTML file, could it be that it gets loaded before the required jquery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please add JQuery library file..

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
This code related to JQuery so without JQuery library we can not run this code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include jQuery library first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
   var count = 1
   $(document).click(function(){
     if(count<=2){
       count+=1;
     }
     else{
       alert("already clicked two times");
     }   
   });
 })  
</script>
```