# videojs is not defined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, video.js

I try to use videojs player inside an advertisement which gets loaded from the adserver asynchronously. It seems the videojs object is not existing. It cannot be a matter of load time, must be something with the context or scope getting lost on the way to DOMContentloaded. 
I googled a lot now, there is a similar question here but it is not answered. "Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined. videojs async loading"
As I have not enough reputation I cannot post a comment on that one, that´s why I repost the question here.

Would be of great help to get some news here..

Cheers 
Steve

Comment: Look into using a callback once the script has loaded, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8586564/740233

Comment: I tried this in several ways, even when I put the complete rest of the code into the onload of the script, videojs remains undefined for further operations.

Comment: It seems like a general mistake I am making, it has to do with loading an external script inside an IIFE via "document.createElement('script')" and keeping it in a global scope, so that classes from inside that script can be reached from the functions of the IIFE. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle code sample so that people can help in detail. Thanks.