# Object inside window is present but undefined when invoked

Tags: javascript

I dynamically added `StripeCheckout` script in the DOM like:

```
var script = document.createElement(`script`);
script.src = `https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js`;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

When I do `console.log(window)` I get :

[image]

But when I do `console.log(window.StripeCheckout)` I freaking get an `undefined`.

Why?

P.S. `window.StripeCheckout` is present when I accessed it directly from the dev console.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why?

Because it takes time to load and execute the script. When you log `window`, by the time you expand the object, the script has loaded and executed. Same for when you run `window.StripeCheckout` in the developer console.

When you hover over that little `[i]` in the console it will also tell you that the "content" of the object was *just* evaluated when you expanded that line.

Additionally, because [JavaScript runs to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion), it is guaranteed that `console.log(window.StripeCheckout)` is executed before the script is evaluated. So the property cannot exist at that moment, even if the script was available immediately.

---

If you want to know when the script loaded have a look at

- [Dynamically load external javascript file, and wait for it to load - without using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8586446/218196)
- [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21294/218196)

Comment: Wow I did not know that. Thanks. I wrapped my code with `window.addEventListener('load', fn)` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";

if (script.readyState){  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                script.readyState == "complete"){
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else {  //Others
    script.onload = function(){
        callback();
    };
}

script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

loadScript("https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js", function(){
  console.log(window.StripeCheckout)
});
```

Comment: Thanks @santho but I prefer the answer by Felix, it explained the problem well which leads me to the right approach.