# adding to window.onload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to add another method call to the window.onload event once it has already
been assigned a method call.

Suppose somewhere in the script I have this assignment...

```
 window.onload = function(){ some_methods_1() };
```

and then later on in the script I have this assignment

```
 window.onload = function(){ some_methods_2() };
```

As it stands, only `some_methods_2` will be called. Is there any way to add to the previous `window.onload` callback without cancelling `some_methods_1` ? (and also without including both `some_methods_1()` and `some_methods_2()` in the same function block).

I guess this question is not really about `window.onload` but a question about javascript in general. I DON'T want to assign something to `window.onload` in such a way that that if another developer were to work on the script and add a piece of code that also uses `window.onload` (without looking at my previous code), he would disable my onload event.

I'm also wondering the same thing about

```
  $(document).ready()
```

in jquery. 
How can I add to it without destroying what came before, or what might come after?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` accumulate. Use it if jQuery's at hand.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you don't have to do anything special. Handlers added via `$(document).ready()` don't overwrite each other, but rather execute in turn:

```
$(document).ready(func1)
...
$(document).ready(func2)
```

---

If you are not using jQuery, you could use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), as demonstrated by Karaxuna, plus [`attachEvent`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljinxrmt.php) for IE<9.

Note that [`onload`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-load) is not equivalent to `$(document).ready()` - the former waits for CSS, images... as well, while the latter waits for the DOM tree only. Modern browsers (and IE since IE9) support the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-domcontentloaded) event on the document, which corresponds to the jQuery `ready` event, but IE<9 does not.

```
if(window.addEventListener){
  window.addEventListener('load', func1)
}else{
  window.attachEvent('onload', func1)
}
...
if(window.addEventListener){
  window.addEventListener('load', func2)
}else{
  window.attachEvent('onload', func2)
}
```

---

If neither option is available (for example, you are not dealing with DOM nodes), you can still do this (I am using `onload` as an example, but other options *are* available for `onload`):

```
var oldOnload1=window.onload;
window.onload=function(){
  oldOnload1 && oldOnload1();
  func1();
}
...
var oldOnload2=window.onload;
window.onload=function(){
  oldOnload2 && oldOnload2();
  func2();
}
```

or, to avoid polluting the global namespace (and likely encountering namespace collisions), using the import/export IIFE pattern:

```
window.onload=(function(oldLoad){
  return function(){
    oldLoad && oldLoad();
    func1();
  }
})(window.onload)
...
window.onload=(function(oldLoad){
  return function(){
    oldLoad && oldLoad();
    func2();
  }
})(window.onload)
```

Comment: You mean "document.attachEvent('onload'...)", not 'load'. ;)

Comment: You should not use document.addEventListener("load") (does not work on my version of firefox) but instead window.addEventListener("load").  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16404380/94102

Comment: @JeremySalwen found a better source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-load. Corrected.

Answer (score 51):

You can use attachEvent(ie8) and addEventListener instead

```
addEvent(window, 'load', function(){ some_methods_1() });
addEvent(window, 'load', function(){ some_methods_2() });

function addEvent(element, eventName, fn) {
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
    else if (element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, fn);
}
```

Comment: so to make it cross-browser compatible, I should use both?
Also, if later on in the script I attach a callback to window.onload after previously using addEventListener, does whatever I assigned with addEventListener get cancelled?

Answer (score 9):

There are basically two ways

1. store the previous value of `window.onload` so your code can call a previous handler if present before or after your code executes
2. using the `addEventListener` approach (that of course Microsoft doesn't like and requires you to use another different name).

The second method will give you a bit more safety if another script wants to use `window.onload` and does it without thinking to cooperation but the main assumption for Javascript is that all the scripts will cooperate like you are trying to do.

Note that a bad script that is not designed to work with other unknown scripts will be always able to break a page for example by messing with prototypes, by contaminating the global namespace or by damaging the dom.

Comment: this is great! what about jquery's $(document).ready() or bind()?

Comment: Do you realize that jquery is just Javascript, don't you? I didn't check but my guess is that it's probably using (2) if available or (1) for older browsers.

Comment: sure of course, I was just asking because $(document).ready() is a bit different from window.onload..."The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded."

Answer (score 5):

This might not be a popular option, but sometimes the scripts end up being distributed in various chunks, in that case I've found this to be a quick fix

```
if(window.onload != null){var f1 = window.onload;}
window.onload=function(){
    //do something

    if(f1!=null){f1();}
}
```

then somewhere else...

```
if(window.onload != null){var f2 = window.onload;}
window.onload=function(){
    //do something else

    if(f2!=null){f2();}
}
```

this will update the onload function and chain as needed

Answer (score 5):

A pure JavaScript (no jQuery) method that would not override existing onload events but instead add to it, would be:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // do your things here
}
```