# Main difference between window.location.href and window.onload() in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using `window.location.href` to load a page and now I have switched over to `window.onload()` function, but the page does not load some contents.

`window.location.href = $(this).val();` is the code I'm using.

How can I write it using `window.onload()` function?

Comment: Did you tried this? http://www.google.com

Comment: Why do you want to switch to `window.onload()` if it is working?

Comment: Are you refering to jquery load method `$(window).load()` or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window.onload` is a property to which you can assign a function that will run when the page has finished loading. It doesn't have a function assigned to it by default, so you can't call it unless you first assign a function to it. It has nothing to do with causing the browser to go to a different URL.

Assigning an `onload` function directly has also been superseded by [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

You could assign a function to it that would set `location.href` to a new value

```
// Don't do this
function redirect() {
    location.href = "http://example.com";
}
addEventListener('load', redirect);
```

… but if you are doing that as soon as the page loads then you should be using an HTTP redirect instead.

Comment: +1, and I can't even see how you could mistake their names...

Comment: `window.onload()` is an event, I don't what you meant by property

Comment: It's an event property.

Comment: @Akam — `load` is an event. `window` is an object. `onload` is a property on that object to which you can assign a function that will act as an event listener for that event.

Comment: Hope I won't get shot down if I reference some [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197055(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I knew that onload can be attached to `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>` and `window` but why a property? generally we call this window event...

Comment: @Akam — Because [that is what they are called in JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.26). And `window.onload` is not an event. `load` is an event.

Comment: that link do not provide an answer to contrast that window.onload is a property not an event, I will research and notify you also, thanks for your effort :)

Comment: I can't find any reference call `window.onload()` property, I knew any thing attached to an object will be a property, but according to [GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) and [adding to window.onload event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564029/adding-to-window-onload-event) and [Handling_events_with_JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript) `window.onload()` is called an event

Comment: `window.onload()` is not a property, it is a call to a function stored in a property of an object. *knew any thing attached to an object will be a property*, no the thing attached to the object is the value of the property. The property is where it is attached to. `window.onload` is where it is attached to, `onload` is a property of the `window` object.

Comment: GlobalEventHandlers.onload says that it is *An event handler for the load event of a window.*, not *An event*. Your second example *adding to window.onload event?* is a question asked by someone using the wrong terminology. Your third example is a wiki page, it isn't a specification and it makes some terminology mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Both are entirely different concepts

The `window.onload` event is a standard event in the DOM,while `window.location.href` returns the location of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are used in totally different context.

**onload is an event**

**location.href is a property**

```
*window.onload*
```

This event is used if you want to take some action the moment page content gets loaded entirely(*this includes all your elements,images etc etc*).So you can assign any function according to your functionality if your project demands some action after content is loaded.

```
*window.location.href*
```

This is used for REDIRECTION purpose.I will use it only when I want my user to go to some different page.

**In your Context**
It is pointless to execute window.location.href on window.onload event.If you are not allowing user to spend some time on the onloading page,then I would suggest to directly load the page that you are including in

```
window.location.href="this url shoulod be loaded directly instead";
```

**why take a longer route when the shorter one is so efficient??**

Comment: thank you..clear explanation. I understood thnk u

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href="url" is what you would call within a javascript function to load some other page(url). It does exactly the same thing what is done when you are clicking a hyperlink on a normal web page.

window.onload() is a an event handler; which you may use to do several things with javascript when an HTML page is loaded. In other words, this will be called, when the page loading event takes place.

**These are two different things.**

For an example, you can use window.location.href="url" to go to another page, and within that new page you can use window.onload() event handler to execute something you want to happen when that page is loaded.

eg:

```
<script>

window.onload=function(){
  document.write("hi! this text was written when the page was being loaded");
}

</script>
```

Thanks.