# Why this addEvent function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie to JS technology. I am taking Javascript Bible as my starting point. That book takes me deep to JS behavior, although some obsolete topics and deprecated functions. A particular code block is not working for me.

I don't know honestly "Is that a deprecated function or browser issue" I've searched addEvent in all resources. Most of the people used `addEventListener` now.

I just need to know the difference. How I can possibly fix this code?

What's the reason it returns an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined". Where I need to define this addEvent?

```js
// **jsb-23-02.js**

// initialize when the page has loaded
addEvent(window, "load", testValues);
var newElem;
var newText;
var toyGlobal = "Gumby";
var aBoy = "Charlie Brown";
var hisDog = "Snoopy";

function showLocal() {
  var toyLocal = "Pokey";
  return toyLocal;
}

function showGlobal() {
  newElem = document.createElement("div");
  newElem.className = "objProperty";
  newText = document.createTextNode("Global version of hisDog is intact: " +
    hisDog);
  // just picked up a global variable value instead
  // of the local variable in the calling function

  newElem.appendChild(newText);
  placeHolderElement.appendChild(newElem);
}

function testValues() {
  // Dangerous ground here -- declaring a global variable in a function
  placeHolderElement = document.getElementById("placeHolder");
  // Now declare the local variable
  var hisDog = "Gromit"; // initializes local version of "hisDog"
  if (placeHolderElement) {
    newElem = document.createElement("div");
    newElem.className = "objProperty";
    newText = document.createTextNode("aBoy is: " + aBoy);
    // just picked up a global variable value
    newElem.appendChild(newText);
    placeHolderElement.appendChild(newElem);
    newElem = document.createElement("div");
    newElem.className = "objProperty";
    newText = document.createTextNode("His toyGlobal is " + toyGlobal);
    newElem.appendChild(newText);
    // just picked up another global variable value
    placeHolderElement.appendChild(newElem);
    // Do not bother with toyLocal here because it will throw undefined
    newElem = document.createElement("div");
    newElem.className = "objProperty";
    newText = document.createTextNode(
      "toyLocal value returned from the showLocal function is: " +
      showLocal());
    newElem.appendChild(newText);
    placeHolderElement.appendChild(newElem);
    newElem = document.createElement("div");
    newElem.className = "objProperty";
    newText = document.createTextNode("Local version of hisDog is: " + hisDog);
    newElem.appendChild(newText);
    // just picked up another global variable value
    placeHolderElement.appendChild(newElem);
    // now call another function that does not set the variable hisDog
    // and display the value. we’ll see that the global value is intact
    showGlobal();
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsb-23-02.js"></script>
<h1>Variable scope</h1>
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `addEvent` in plain JS. Are you looking for [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: What is addEvent? You are missing a function addEvent, but all new browsers recognise addEventListener - you likely used to have some script like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent

Comment: That book is almost 10 years old. You might as well learn a separate language. Here's an article I found from 2005 referencing it: [`addEvent()` considered harmful](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma `window.addEventListener("load", testValues);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems pretty likely that your code was copied from something like [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564029/adding-to-window-onload-event), which defines `addEvent` as a DRY way to call `addEventListener` if it exists, or to call `attachEvent` (a very obsolete method for use in Internet Explorer which does the same thing as `addEventListener`):

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, fn) {
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
    else if (element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, fn);
}
```

Like all non-built-in functions, you need to define the `addEvent` function in order to be able to call it.

`addEventListener` works just fine in all major browsers, including Internet Explorer 9+ (released in 2011; only a few people are using IE nowadays, and those that are are almost exclusively using IE11.). I'd suggest ditching `addEvent` and `attachEvent` entirely, and just using `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. So it is not working because of browser. right? It's an old book. Can you recommend any JS book with updated modules?

Comment: No, your `addEvent` isn't working because you didn't define the function first - all you need to do is to define the function first, like in the answer. I don't know of Javascript books, everything I've learned, I've learned online, primarily from Google (which often points to Stack Overflow :P )

Comment: Define means how? function addEvent() or any other way. I can't get it. Help me to get over from this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you just need to put that `function addEvent` into your code, so that it's defined when you try to call `addEvent` afterwards. eg `function AddEvent(....) { ... } /* and then you can call it */ addEvent(window, "load", testValues);`