# remove a respawning html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

It may look like a simple question at first sight but it is not; I got the following code:

```
window.intercomSettings = {
"app_id": "ewqfsdjh",
"user_id": "user",
"real_name": " ",
"name": "user",
"email": "user@user.com",
"created_at": 225028599901,
};
(function() {
var w = window;
var ic = w.Intercom;
if (typeof ic === "function") {
    ic('reattach_activator');
    ic('update', intercomSettings);
} else {
    var d = document;
    var i = function() {
        i.c(arguments)
    };
    i.q = [];
    i.c = function(args) {
        i.q.push(args)
    };
    w.Intercom = i;

    function l() {
        var s = d.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/ewqfsdjh';
        var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
    if (w.attachEvent) {
        w.attachEvent('onload', l);
    } else {
        w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
    }
}
})()
```

http://js.do/diomerda/81708 which outputs quite a lot of html.

Say I'd like to delete (or hide) the entire button (intercom-container div) by javascript once the page gets loaded. How would you accomplish this?

I tried

```
window.onload = function(){document.getElementById('intercom-container').outerHTML='';}
```

and many variations, but the button keeps respawning...

Maybe I could append some code to modify the button respawn behaviour.

Comment: please fix your code by identing it

Comment: Now you deleted your code, which is bad, because it might be deleted from 3rd party links, so you'll get even more down-votes IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you posted does not by itself generate any HTML. It *asynchronously* loads a library responsible for bootstrapping the interface. `window.onload` fires before the library is loaded, so you are effectively trying to hide the element before it's ever created.

Instead, looking at the [API docs](https://docs.intercom.io/install-on-your-web-product/intercom-javascript-api#intercomshutdown), you can use

```
Intercom('shutdown');
```

This is both safer and cleaner than trying to hide the element yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much indeed, this clarifies a lot. So, which code should I place to be sure that Intercom('shutdown'); is executed after the library is loaded?

Comment: Since unfortunately I just can not write that instruction right after the rest of the code, but just before it.

Comment: `Intercom('shutdown')` seems to be deferred until the library is loaded, so there is no need to bind to any events or wait until the library is loaded. Why can't you place this line right after the Intercom loader?

Comment: Because the intercom script is automatically added at the bottom of the page (via a server side script which I can not manage). Anyway you pointed out the exact way to go! Thank you very much indeed. I'll probabily get an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486309/how-to-make-script-execution-wait-until-jquery-is-loaded for the last part of my issue.

Comment: just for reference I ended up using the following code: function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.innerHTML = "Intercom('shutdown');";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

Comment: That seems like serious overkill... If you want to just defer some code until the next event loop, use `setTimeout(function () { Intercom('shutdown'); })` ([demo](http://js.do/code/81713)). This is not more reliable than your approach, but it's definitely cleaner. The combination of waiting for the `window.onload` event, and then injecting more code into the parser using an extra `<script>` tag is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('intercom-container').style.display = 'none';