# How to load inline script after JQuery and JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have several inline `<script>` tags that appear in the middle of my HTML document. These all require Jquery, and a couple need JQuery UI.

JQuery and JQuery UI are linked at the bottom of the document.

How can I have the inline scripts run after JQuery and UI are ready.

I have tried wrapping the inline scripts with this with no success:

```
$(window).load(function() {
//
 });
```

And I have also tried darbio's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486309/how-to-make-script-execution-wait-until-jquery-is-loaded/17914854#17914854) using:

```
function defer(method) {
    if (window.jQuery)
        method();
    else
        setTimeout(function() { defer(method) }, 50);
}
defer(function () {
    alert("jQuery is now loaded");
});
```

But this didn't seem to work either?

Comment: If you have scripts in the middle of the HTML that use jQuery, you should load it at the top, not at the bottom.

Comment: Why do you need the scripts to be in the middle of the HTML document? Put them at the bottom, after loading jQuery.

Comment: `$(window).load(function() ...)` requires jQuery. You can't use it before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: BTW, `$(window).load()` is deprecated, you should use `$(window).on("load", ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should load jQuery and jquery-ui in your header if you want to run jQuery inside the DOM,

alternatively you could add `window.onload()` to all your script to prevent running it before the DOM is ready

src: [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: Am required to keep things where they are otherwise I would rearrange to be in loading order.