# Wait for jQuery to load in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Wordpress loads jQuery automatically. I want to use it, but I get:

> jQuery is not defined

This is because various plugins mess with the ordering of scripts. So there's no guarantee that my script will load AFTER jQuery is loaded. So if it loads before, I get that error.

Can I wrap my script in something that waits for jQuery to load, and then executes my script?

Notes

- I don't want to manually load jQuery, because then I'll break various plugins... I must let Wordpress load it as usual
- I'm not a PHP person, so I don't want to hack the theme... I just want to wrap my script in a cross-browser "jquery waiting script"

Comment: See also [wait for jQuery loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486309/how-to-make-script-execution-wait-until-jquery-is-loaded)

Comment: @Adder Thanks. But that talks about using `defer`, which I cannot control as Wordpress controls jquery, and about document ready which is not relevant because jquery is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions in `window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded` will be runned after `jQuery` is defined, so if you push all your inizializations in `window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded` you can be sure that they will be runned after `jQuery`

```html
<script>
    if (!window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded) {
        window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded = [];

        //delete Object.defineProperty; //add this if you want to check the support
        if (typeof (Object.defineProperty) === "function") {
            Object.defineProperty(window, "jQuery", {
                set: function (value) {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $.each(window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded, function (index, fn) {
                            fn();
                        });
                    }, 0);
                    Object.defineProperty(window, "jQuery", {value: value});
                },

                configurable: true
            });
        } else {
            nIntervId = window.setInterval(function () {
                if (typeof (jQuery) !== "undefined") {
                    $.each(window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded, function (index, fn) {
                        fn();
                    });
                    clearInterval(nIntervId);
                }
            }, 10);
        }
    }
    window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded.push(function () {
        (function ($) {
            console.log("After jquery is loaded");
        })(jQuery);
    });

</script>
<script>
    window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded.push(function () {
        (function ($) {
            console.log("After jquery is do something else");
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can read more abount [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), you can check the cross browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=defineProperty)

Comment: Thanks - looks interesting, I'm testing it now...Do you know whether this has cross browser support?

Comment: I've added a link so you can check it, I try to make some changes to the snippet , so you can cover browsers that don't support Object.defineProperty

Comment: I don't think it is needed you have a polyfill at the end of page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: I have changed the snippet, jquery 3.3.1 is using  Object.defineProperty so I've changed to 1.11.1

Answer (score 3):

IMHO when 'load' is triggered you can use jQuery:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing exactly this because it's so straightforward / easy... But do you know if it's got good cross browser support? In my experience when something is so simple it's because the older nasty browsers don't support it :)

Comment: Yes it has very good browser support, please see: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

You can also use `window.onload = function() { /* your code */ };`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then use $j

Tom

Comment: The problem is jQuery is not even loaded yet - it's not a noconflict issue.

Comment: Ok. I had this error (not defined) sometimes und solved it like this. But usually I don`t move jQuery around.

Comment: Yes in that case it's because Wordpress runs jquery in noconflict mode, so you must use `jQuery` instead of `$`. But that assumes jQuery is already loaded, so it solves a related but different problem.