# Extending bootstrap jQuery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, extend

I would like to extend `$.fn.modal` in Bootstrap/jQuery so my extended version "does things" before a modal is initialized by passing extra options. I tried this like I do some times to extend jQuery prototypes:

```
var modal = $.fn.modal;

$.fn.modal = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
    modal.apply(this, arguments);
}

$('#modal').modal(); // fails
```

The example above does not work, although the same pattern works for many other non-bootstrap jQuery prototypes.

Here’s a fiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/eTWSb/ (just comment the override stuff to see it working).

I was under the impression that cloning a function and then calling it as a "super" is a viable option when you want to add custom functionality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Does not work"* as in your code has no effect? Or the modal stop working altogether? What exactly does your code do? Is it something that may be overwritten by the modal code?

Comment: *Does not work* as in the modal is not initialized anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/eTWSb/

Comment: Is editting the original `bootstrap-modal.js` an option?

Comment: Well that's just weird. I can't figure out why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @PetrMarek nope, I want this to be thrown into any bootstrap project. Like a steroid for bootstrap modals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I figured it out. When overriding `$.fn.modal` I’m also removing the **default options** that bootstrap placed in `$.fn.modal.defaults` (why?).

So when I extended it, I lost the default `show: true` option that actually shows the modal...

This solves it (but the constructor is lost unless you copy that too):

```
var modal = $.fn.modal,
    defaults = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults);

$.fn.modal = function(options) {
    options = $.extend( defaults, options );
    this.each(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
    return modal.call( this, options );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210578/david) is correct, but to do this, you have to be sure that jQuery is loaded, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865/checking-if-jquery-is-loaded-using-javascript), so the final solution :

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        //modal extension
        var modal = $.fn.modal,
        defaults = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults);
        $.fn.modal = function(options) {
        options = $.extend( defaults, options );
        this.each(function() {
          // do stuff
        });
        return modal.call( this, options );
        };
    }
}
```