# Jquery loading Errors

Tags: jquery, load

Yesterday, I had `jquery 1.8.0` and all are working fine. But to get advanced jquery., I installed [Nuget.Migrate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Migrate/), from then my troube had started. 
Firstly, while trying to resolve the issue.,  I have read that `live` is removed in jquery 1.9, in `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` I replaced all the `live` with `on`. But since that doesnot resolved the issue, I roll backed the changes back to `live`. But the problem was persisted.

Secondly., I removed all the reference of `jquery 1.9` in my code., uninstalled the Nuget.Migrate., even removed from pakage.config. And I added `jquery.1.8.3`. 
But, The problems was still on.

Hence, I decided to undo my pending changes and took the server version for smooth running.
(in VS 12)

But Still I am getting the error as., (I changed the jquery to `1.8.0` , `1.8.3`, but no use) .

**My Doubt :**
 Whether installation and uninstallation of [Nuget.Migrate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Migrate/) would have made any 
side-effects in my local machine??? 
I tried almost 5 hours., but I cannot resolve the issue.

[image]

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined                      jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:163
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined                      jquery.validate.js:1116
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined                      jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:345
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined                           AccruedAccountMap:32
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'         AccruedAccountMap:452
```

Also, I have cross-checked, all the functions using jquery are inside `$(document).ready` function only.

Comment: @close-voter reason for voting to close, please??

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on - is jQuery definitely loading? Is jQuery being loaded above your other scripts?

Comment: @Joe Definitely jquery is loading., the screen shot itself is proof for that. But I check with the order. Also , `Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' Actually this function was working previously , but after this drama, it stops working.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's loading? `jQuery is not defined` and `$ is not defined` only occur when jQuery **isn't** loaded. Please use the code here to check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7341884/2287470

Comment: @Joe you are correct joe. Jquery is not loaded. I digged the whole pakage and finally included it. The mistake is with my side. k. Then I'll try to rectify the other error myself, instead of asking it again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add following links only,remove other script from your page and try

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: the core problem is `jquery 1.9.1 ` is not supported by `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`. I tried with 1.8, from ajax.googleapis too but that makes no difference

Comment: then you download jQuery Migrate 1.1.0  script add after 1.9 script