# checkbox change event not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange

i'm Trying to include an onclick event for a checkbox in my laravel application

This is my Input Section

```
<input type="checkbox" id="early_access" name="early_access">
```

And the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#early_access').change(function() {
    alert("booyah");
  });
});
```

The function is not working ..

Comment: Athul, the code is perfectly fine and must work as expected, Do you see any errors in your console??

Comment: Did you try by give a simple alert to check your jquery working in this page ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim yes i did and jquery is working perfectly ... other functions are there which are working too

Comment: @Reddy no errors in console  .. nothing at all

Comment: I guess there can be another checkbox and some HTML which might cause issues, Can you post your complete code. Or you yourself can create a JSFiddle and you will be able to find out the issue.

Comment: @Reddy yes that was the exact problem

Comment: glad you fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys i found the problem and solved it
Unfortunately the frontend designer had some other function running for changing the style of checkbox and it was inherited from the master layout ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
});
});
```

this was running instead of my script :( .. when i removed it everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you [checked if your jquery was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865/checking-if-jquery-is-loaded-using-javascript)?

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}
```

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#early_access').on("change", function() {
        alert("booyah");
    });
 });
```

If you can, I suggest that you use your selector `#early_access` as an argument.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on("change", "#early_access" function() {
         alert("booyah");
     });
});
```

It might not be relevant with an id but if you use a class based attribute and you dynamically change the DOM, it will still be responsive. But that might be beyond the point of your question.

Comment: so how does this solve his problem? what was his problem?

Comment: @Wistar yes jquery is working fine
and i also tried out everything in your answer .. but  still the function is not triggering , there are many other functions on the same page that are working perfectly ... when it comes to checkbox i'm facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely fine see this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/avinash8526/nL1crxn0/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#early_access').change(function() {
    alert("I will only work with check uncheck");
  });
});
```

Further you have onchange event applied, hence this alert will only work if you check/uncheck this box