# Check if script tag is loading/pending execution or already loaded and executed

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
var a_script_from_my_dom = document.querySelector("script")
```

How can I test, preferably without the use of third party libraries, if this script has finished loading and executing? Assume that the script may have been inserted dynamically using `createElement / appendChild`. Also assume that I have no power to change the loaded script to set specific variables or trigger specific behaviour.

I know that I can attach an onload handler, but if the script has already loaded, the handler won't run.

Comment: You'll have to find something that the script affects and test that element to see if it has been affected as it should have been.

Comment: First of all, an `alert` interrupts the user. That is in no way the point. My goal is runtime dependency management. Secondly, I cannot depend on particular side effects from the loaded script - the main use case are libraries from CDN's. I don't control these.

Comment: You said this was for testing, not production. That's why I suggested `alert()`. Additionally, you didn't elaborate until after I made that comment.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. Test as in programatically testing.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any property in a `script` element that holds the status of loading it. It looks like this just isn't possible.

Comment: That's also my draft conclusion so far. I hope someone will prove me wrong. :-/

Comment: What do text contents of script define and do?

Comment: If you know what the script does you can easily check whether it has defined any objects, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865

Comment: I recognise your point, but the solution I am looking for must be generic and can make no assumptions about side effects.