# client-side disabling manual input in p:spinner not working

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces `<p:spinner>`, I want to disable manual input, by setting the `<input>` tag of the spinner to readonly. I have tried to achieve it by using jQuery:

- `$('.ui-spinner-input').prop('readonly', true);`
- `$('#dtProduct:spinnerQty').prop('readonly', true);`
- `$('#dtProduct:spinnerQty_input').prop('readonly', true);`

Non of the above works. I have also try to select it by tag name and loop through it:

```
$("input").each(function() 
{
    alert("");
    if($(this).hasClass("ui-spinner-input")) {
    alert("");
    }
});
```

doesn't work neither, not even alert anything. I am sure that my jQuery is working by using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341884/4541141).

Below is the screenshot of the element source code from Google Chrome

[image]

My class name and id looks right, but it just not working at all, any idea?

Comment: Escape meta characters, Use `$('#dtProduct\\:spinnerQty_input')`, Although `$('.ui-spinner-input').prop('readonly', true);` should have worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Comment: Please when having issues, check all >35 upvote questions or answers. 80-90% certain the solution in is in there

Comment: @satpal: OP forgot to take the `:0:` part in it into account. Looks like it is in an iterating component

Comment: @Kukeltje the first query in the question uses a class, not an id. Newbie, any errors in your browser's Javascript console?

Comment: @Kukeltje, Still need to  escape meta characters https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Satpal No, no error at all. I try to escape `$('#dtProduct\\:spinnerQty_input')` still not working

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, it is in an iterating component, which is `dataTable`. What should I do with `:0:`?

Comment: @Newbie, `$('#dtProduct\\:0\\:spinnerQty_input')`

Comment: @Satpal doesn't work either.

Comment: did I miss something in `$('.ui-spinner-input').prop('readonly', true);`? this looks fine. But it just not work

Comment: What does `$('.ui-spinner-input')` return on the developer console commandline?

Comment: @Kukeltje it returns `r.fn.init(6) [...]` which `...` is all of my spinner components id and class, like `input#dtProduct:0:spinnerQty_input.ui-spinner-input.ui-inputfield.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all`

Comment: So the selector works! What does `$('.ui-spinner-input')[0]` show?

Comment: @Kukeltje it returns the `<input>` tag of my first spinner. It looks good, but why just won't work?

Comment: I have figured out the answer, thank you all for your help.

Comment: So your title was as stated earlier completely wrong. The selectors ARE working. I improved your title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    disableInput();
});

function disableInput()
{
    $('.ui-spinner-input').bind("keydown", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.ui-spinner-input').focus(function() {
        $(this).blur();
    });
}
```

`$(document).ready(function() {});` is the reason. The function within this body will be loaded after all the DOMs are ready.