# jQuery - Require to add setTimeout function will run every 5 seconds to check if jQuery is defined or not upto 1 minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I would like to add setTimeout function will run **every 5 seconds** to check if jQuery is defined or up to **1 minute**.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    setInterval(function() {
        setInterval(function() { alert("Message to triggred 5 seconds"); }, 5000);  
            alert("Message to triggred 60 seconds");
        }, 60000);
});
```

tried to use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` also, but not enough.

Comment: Found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865/checking-if-jquery-is-loaded-using-javascript .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two interval in your code you just need one and a condition to stop interval.

```js
var count = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (window.$ || window.jQuery) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    alert("jquery found");
    return;
  }
  count++;
  if (count >= 12) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    alert("Message to triggred 60 seconds");
  }
  alert("Message to triggred 5 seconds");
}, 5000);
```

If you just want to know if jQuery loaded or not, you can just check `(window.$ || window.jQuery)` values at window.onload.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using jQuery to check if jQuery exists. You'd need to use plain javascript to perform the check. Something like this:

```
var startTime = performance.now();
window.onload = checkJqueryExists;

function checkJqueryExists() {
    var lapsedTime = performance.now() - startTime;
    if (!window.jQuery && lapsedTime < 60000 ) {
        setTimeout(checkJqueryExists, 5000);
    }
}
```