# javascript window-dollarsign method ; colon notation in alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

in regards to:
[Checking if jquery is loaded using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7341865/11913742)

```js
alert(window.$?1:0)
```

is suggested in a comment on the original question

- What is the interpretation of everything in this short line of code (what does it actually do?)

I believed that this would show alert "1" when jquery is loaded, but it actually shows alert "1" in a basic HTML page generated by d-o-c-Tab in vscode.

My initial belief was due to $ as a synonym for jquery in some cases however in most cases [when jquery is not used  others it seems to be a synonym for document.getElementByID](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&q=dollar%20sign%20%22document.getElementById%22)

I do not have the reputation to comment on the original question yet.

Comment: It's a [Ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator); effectively an `if` condition condensed to a single line. Also It would be more reliable to use `window.jQuery` as that's less likely to be stolen than the `$` variable.

Comment: What's your question?  What's `?:` or what's `window.$`?

Comment: Hi freedomn-m, the question is actually both inquiries, as you have described, simultaneously. The page linked by Rory explains "?:" quite well. As for "window.$" it seems just further practice/experience with javascript/browser standards on my side is necessary to know in just how many cases this identifier is used.